# Line style of errorbar caps

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to use a different line style of errorbar caps (matplotlib/pyplot).
Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np   
fig = plt.figure()
default_size = fig.get_size_inches() 
fig.set_size_inches((default_size[0]*2, default_size[1]*2))
x = np.array([math.log(1/8100,10), math.log(1/2025,10), math.log(1/900,10), math.log(1/225,10), math.log(1/100,10), math.log(1/25,10), math.log(1/9,10), math.log(1/4,10)])  
err = np.array([0.0, 0.0511919632, 0.0901150419, 0.2201860606, 0.2515436715, 0.3060438313, 0.2990926056, 0.1011243898, 0.0, 0.0541676892, 0.0405075604, 0.0634289157, 0.1107514665, 0.1821387670, 0.2449796704, 0.2120694129, 0.0, 0.0474213990, 0.0423746910, 0.0409827213, 0.0553901830, 0.1136068198, 0.1878500012, 0.2665951693]) 
y = np.array([0.9779133796, 1.2868842184, 1.2282204495, 1.4052313201, 1.4373060067, 1.2971323397, 1.2214902860, 1.0246309381, 1.4085423946, 1.6703182160, 1.7321032153, 1.8226118650, 1.7983345102, 1.6748284241, 1.4835424022, 1.1404502085, 1.4348299503, 1.7042673230, 1.7949013577, 1.8661885162, 1.8814286876, 1.7666944544, 1.6410772747, 1.2509882123])
plt.plot(x[0:8], y[0:8], linestyle="solid", label="B", marker="s", color="black")
plt.plot(x[0:8], y[8:16], linestyle="dashed", label="P", marker="o", color="black")
plt.plot(x[0:8], y[16:24], linestyle="dotted", label="W", marker="*", color="black")
plt.errorbar(x[0], y[0], yerr=err[0], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='blue', color='blue')
plt.errorbar(x[1], y[1], yerr=err[1], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='green', color='green')
plt.errorbar(x[2], y[2], yerr=err[2], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='red', color='red')
plt.errorbar(x[3], y[3], yerr=err[3], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='yellow', color='yellow')
plt.errorbar(x[4], y[4], yerr=err[4], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='orange', color='orange')
plt.errorbar(x[5], y[5], yerr=err[5], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='purple', color='purple')
plt.errorbar(x[6], y[6], yerr=err[6], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='magenta', color='magenta')
plt.errorbar(x[7], y[7], yerr=err[7], marker='s', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='navy', color='navy')
plt.errorbar(x[0], y[8], yerr=err[8], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='blue', color='blue')
plt.errorbar(x[1], y[9], yerr=err[9], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='green', color='green')
plt.errorbar(x[2], y[10], yerr=err[10], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='red', color='red')
plt.errorbar(x[3], y[11], yerr=err[11], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='yellow', color='yellow')
plt.errorbar(x[4], y[12], yerr=err[12], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='orange', color='orange')
plt.errorbar(x[5], y[13], yerr=err[13], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='purple', color='purple')
plt.errorbar(x[6], y[14], yerr=err[14], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='magenta', color='magenta')
plt.errorbar(x[7], y[15], yerr=err[15], marker='o', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='navy', color='navy')
plt.errorbar(x[0], y[16], yerr=err[16], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='blue', color='blue')
plt.errorbar(x[1], y[17], yerr=err[17], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='green', color='green')
plt.errorbar(x[2], y[18], yerr=err[18], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='red', color='red')
plt.errorbar(x[3], y[19], yerr=err[19], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='yellow', color='yellow')
plt.errorbar(x[4], y[20], yerr=err[20], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='orange', color='orange')
plt.errorbar(x[5], y[21], yerr=err[21], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='purple', color='purple')
plt.errorbar(x[6], y[22], yerr=err[22], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='magenta', color='magenta')
plt.errorbar(x[7], y[23], yerr=err[23], marker='*', capsize=12, markersize="12", mfc='navy', color='navy')
plt.savefig("plot.pdf")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I meant not using a horizontal line, but rather a >----< (rotate by 90 degrees to see what I mean) or o---o, etc. So anything other than |-----| then overlapping bars don't hide one another:

[image]

Comment: ... and the code that produces this...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I just edited the post with the code.

Comment: Practice making the example a [[MCVE]] -- something I can paste into a file and run immediately. E.g: Dummy data, all the import statements, and no more lines than are needed to show all the problem cases.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @cphlewis. I just edited the code, to be a MCV example.

Comment: You could still minimize it -- try only two x-values, one of which has coinciding errorbars and the other doesn't. Note that this is building a test case into the plot, which is also a good habit.

Comment: (I am looking into customizing the errorbar cross-bars; looks like it would be a new feature.)

Comment: @cphlewis Yes, I couId minimize as you described... 
I could even remove the code now and just leave the minimum code in which different error bars intersect, but I think it is interesting to keep the way it is, as it allows the reader to check how the other error bars are (which do not intersect), making it look like the plots have no problems.

Comment: @cphlewis, Great. Thank you for your effort. Really looks like it would be a new feature.

Comment: @Marco yet minimize it so that it doesn't have the scroll bars.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, I just edited the code to remove white lines. It removed the vertical scroll bar. The horizontal scroll bar cannot be removed. Considering the size of the code, the scroll bar should remain vertical or horizontal. If it is preferable to remain the vertical scroll bar instead of horizontal, let me know so that I can make the necessary modifications.

Comment: It remains a vertical scroll bar, but a minimal one.

Comment: You should still remove some, and make the image match the code then

Comment: See e.g. my answer on how a [mcve] could look like - only using two errorbars and a lot less data. However, I must say that it is by far better to have a not-so-minimal complete and verifiable example than a minimal, but neither complete nor verifiable example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use any symbol you like as errorbar cap.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(4)
y=np.log(np.array([4,2,5,7]))
yerr = [1,3,2,5]

l, caps, c = plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr, marker='s', capsize=4, markersize=12, 
                        mfc='blue', color='blue')
l2, caps2, c2 = plt.errorbar(x,y+4,yerr, marker='s', capsize=8, markersize=12, 
                        mfc='limegreen', color='limegreen')

for cap in caps:
    cap.set_marker("^")
for cap in caps2:
    cap.set_marker(ur"$\u266B$")

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, as you notice, both markers of an errorbar are the same. I.e. something like
`<---<` (`.set_marker("^")`) or `o---o` (`.set_marker("o")`) is clearly possible, while something like `>---<` is not - or at least not that easily.

In order to produce different caps for upper and lower bound (`>---<`), one may split the errorbar creation up into 3 parts: the errorbars themselves without caps plus one plot for the upper bounds and one for the lower ones, respectively.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(4)
y=np.log(np.array([4,2,5,7]))
yerr = np.array([1,3,2,5])

plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr, marker='s', capsize=0, markersize=12, color='blue')
plt.plot(x,y+yerr, marker="v", ls="", color="blue", ms=8)
plt.plot(x,y-yerr, marker="^", ls="", color="blue", ms=8)

plt.errorbar(x,y+4,yerr, marker='o', capsize=0, markersize=12, color='limegreen')
plt.plot(x,y+4+yerr, marker="v", ls="", color='limegreen', ms=8)
plt.plot(x,y+4-yerr, marker="^", ls="", color='limegreen', ms=8)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes... this solved.... thanks! I still had to change, for each vertical (Y points), specific markers (several unicode characters, with no fill, for easy visualization), to differentiate them. And for each line I left with a different color, totalizing 3 colors. I'll post the plot here.

Comment: Final plot: https://imgur.com/a/5EYhR Even so, the last blue cap for upper bound, was almost invisible by the last red cap for upper bound ... :(